# how to request permission when running flutter app as a web app in android or ios device?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-web

In flutter the "permission_handler" package only supports native android and ios application for its functioning.

But when running the application as a web app in a web view or a browser in user's device ? how do we handle permissions ?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "web app in a web view" as a webview is inside a native app and therefore have the same permission limitations as regular native apps. Browser has its own permissions, so HTML5/PWAs have their own API: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Permissions_API

Comment: I'm a bit confuse, you are referencing this as flutter web, or webview, both are very different topic.